# Why inserting primary key does not affect sequence?

Tags: postgresql, primary-key, postgresql-9.5

When inserting rows with implicit primary keys, it seems not affect primary key sequence and then, when trying to insert without PK, it fails:

```
create table testtable(
  id serial primary key,
  data integer not null
);
```

Insert with PK (for example on data migration):

```
insert into testtable ( id, data ) values ( 1,2 ), ( 2,2 ), ( 3,2 ), ( 4,2 );
INSERT 0 4
```

Inserting new data, without PK:

```
insert into testtable ( data ) values ( 4 ), ( 5 ), ( 6 ), ( 7 );
ERROR:  duplicate key value violates unique constraint "testtable_pkey"
DETAIL:  Key (id)=(1) already exists.
```

Why sequence is not set on the max value after first `INSERT`? Should I control sequences after inserts with PK? Is there way to have sequence automatically on right track?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The reason for this behavior is that the sequence is accessed in the `DEFAULT` value of the column, and the default value is not used when the column is inserted explicitly.

The only way to achieve what you want that I can imagine is to have a trigger that modifies the sequence after an insert, but I think that would be a slow and horrible solution.

The best way to proceed would be to adjust the sequence once after you are done with the migration.

Comment: Exactly as I thought about it as solution. Hoped I am wrong ;) Thank you for confirmation!